# Showing Pivot Table Detail in a new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with an interesting job today.
I have a huge master sheet from all of my business sales which I create a a pivot table by month (see simplified version below). I would like to create a macro that will show all the details of each row label on a separate workbook, rather than same workbook as my code current runs.
P.s it would also be great to have each seperate worksheet labelled by there row label (e.g. January, February, March etc)

[image]

My Current Macro that only shows details on same worksheet

```
Sub MakeReports()
    Dim c As Range
    With Sheets("Pivot Table").PivotTables(1)
        For Each c In .DataBodyRange.Resize(0, 1)
           c.ShowDetail = True
           c.Move
        Next c
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: [`Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.move) the newly created sheet to a new workbook?

Comment: yes that would be it! whilst deleting the old worksheets on the same workbook, i dont want them clogging up the tracker

Comment: From the documentation (link above): "If you don't specify either Before or After, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook that contains the moved sheet."

Comment: ok so I have amended the code and it has not worked. run time error "1004".

Comment: `c` is not a `Worksheet`.

Comment: the range of row labels I use is dynamic. sometimes there will be  4 sheets looking at quarterly data, 6 months half year etc.